# Difficulties with displaying the smallest number when user inputs 10 numbers

Tags: java, while-loop

The program asks the user to input 10 numbers and it is supposed to display the smallest number of all of the 10 numbers the user inputted. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
  public class SmallestNumber {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

    int counter=10;
    int smallest=0; 
    int number;

    System.out.println("Enter a number");


    while(counter>0)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        number=input.nextInt();

    if(number<smallest)
        //stores number to largest
        smallest=number;
        //decrement counter
        counter=counter-1;}

        System.out.println("Smallest number is "+smallest);




 }}
```

What am I doing wrong

Comment: smallest starts at 0 - so it will always be smaller than any positive input number and you'll just get 0 output.

Initializing smallest to Integer.MAX_VALUE will work.

Comment: Try assigning the smallest number to the first number. Then start comparing

Answer (score 0):

```
int smallest=0;
```

should be changed.

You should set it to a big number initially, like
    int smallest=Integer.MAX_VALUE;

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your 'smallest' number is always 0.  That is because it starts at 0, and no input will be smaller than that (unless the user inputs negative numbers).

Change your code to make smallest equal to the first user input, and for every subsequent input, test against that value.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SmallestNumber {

public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

int counter=10;
int smallest; 
int number;

System.out.println("Enter a number");


while(counter>0)
{
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    number=input.nextInt();

    if (counter == 10)
    {
        smallest = number;
    }
    else
    {
        if(number<smallest)
        //stores number to largest
        smallest=number;
    }
    //decrement counter
    counter=counter-1;}

    System.out.println("Smallest number is "+smallest);
 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your Problem is that you already start with smallest=0. This way the user needs to enter numbers smaller than 0 to be smaller than the inital value.

You should initialize smallest with a really big number (like int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;)

Answer (score 0):

First put System.out.println out side of while loop. 
Second if you are considering to evaluate smallest number to be from the 10 input numbers then alter the logic.

First accept first input and store it in the smallest.

Set the counter to 9. Something like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SmallestNumber {

public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

int counter=9;
int smallest; 
int number;

System.out.println("Enter a number");
smallest=input.nextInt();

while(counter>0)
{
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    number=input.nextInt();

    if(number<smallest)
    //stores number to largest
    smallest=number;

    //decrement counter
    counter=counter-1;}
}
System.out.println("Smallest number is "+smallest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SmallestNumber {

public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

int counter=10;
int smallest=0; 
int number;

//System.out.println("Enter a number");


while(counter>0)
{
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    number=input.nextInt();
    if (counter==10)
        smallest=number;


if(number<smallest)
    //stores number to largest
    smallest=number;
    //decrement counter
    counter=counter-1;}

    System.out.println("Smallest number is "+smallest);




 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this algorithm.

```
while(counter>0)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        number=input.nextInt();

        if(counter==10)
            smallest=number;

        else{

            if(number<smallest){ 
               smallest=number;
               counter=counter-1;
            }
        }
 }

  System.out.println("Smallest number is "+smallest);
```